# KVO notification not sent when using the super class' setter

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, kvc

I have a ClassA that defines a property:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint property;
@end
```

The implementation doesn't override the accessors.

ClassB overrides the setter to do some additional work:

```
- (void)setProperty:(CGPoint)property {
    [super setProperty:property];
    [self someAdditionalWork];
}
```

In an other method of ClassB I try to set this property via the super setter, to skip the additional work:

```
- (void)otherMethodInClassB {
    // ...
    super.property = newValue;
    // ...
}
```

When I do this, the KVO notifications for the property are not sent. If I do the same thing, but use `self`, the KVO notifications work as expected:

```
- (void)otherMethodInClassB {
    // ...
    self.property = newValue;
    // ...
}
```

What's going on here? Is this the expected behavior? I couldn't find anything that would say so.

Comment: Shouldn't that property have the `assign` attribute?

Comment: @trojanfoe Isn't that the default for primitives?

Comment: Yeah you could be right about that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is documented, but this is the expected behavior.

Automatic KVO notifications work by silently changing your instance's class in runtime from original `ClassB` to an auto-generated subclass `NSKVONotifying_ClassB` which overrides all the required setter methods to do those `willChange...`/`didChange...` calls for you. By calling super, you effectively skip all that magic and invoke the original setter, which only does bare value assignment.

P.S. This blog post digs into deeper details of this: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html

Comment: Hm, interesting. But wouldn't the super setter also be silently changed then? Is there a recommended way to fix this problem? Should I deactivate automatic KVO in ClassB and add the will/didChange calls in my setter?

Comment: The `super` calls still invoke the original superclass, or course, just as methods like `class` and `className` keep pretending like nothing happened — there may be more quirks, I'm not sure. The easiest way to workaround your situation would be to manually invoke `willChange...`/`didChange...` around call to `super`. I can't advice better without knowing what are you trying to accomplish, but problems like this may be an indication that you need to rethink your class design and/or implementation.